# Ask iOS to execute an app or services periodically

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I'd like to have a game in which everytime one of your friends beats your highscore, it sends you a notification.

There is many ways to do it. But I would like to know if there is a way to "ask" your iphone to call one of your applications or services which then contains the code that checks the leaderboards and push a notification if needed.

Not sure if this is clear enough ;p

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try something like this..then you must do this from within the app. .that is system won't tell your app to check codes.. you open the app and then press a button or something to check leader boards.

So there is no way to ask your iPhone!

best way is to have an option in within the app through which user confirms that he wants to receive notifications on high score beaten..then you keep his high score on your server..and if someone breaks that.. post a notification from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your highest score must be stored somewhere. If you store it on your server, then you can use web services so that every time the user got a highest mark(on his/her iPhone), send a web service request to the server and get the results back.

On the server side, all you have to care is creating a user's friend list and the highest score of every player.

Hope this helps.